# Regex to match/remove whitespace within a group

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to format a block of text to be easily searchable. Most of the text is formatted normally, but there are occasional blocks in which the words are split into groups of 1 and 2 characters (the text is sourced from PDFs). Within only those blocks, I would like to remove all whitespace characters.

The target language is Python. I've written a regex to identify the blocks:
`((?:\s\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\b){3,})`
But I'm stumped as to how to match/remove only the whitespace from within those blocks.

It would be nice if a solution could be found which uses the Python regex functions i.e. re.sub, although all suggestions are welcomed.

Here's an example of the text, with a block of split characters:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Registration Counter - Prefunction Area Level 1 09:00 - 12:00 Registration 12:00 - 13:00 Lunch 13:00 - 19:00 Registration PROGRAM AT GLANCE S a tu rd a y, S e p te m b e r 1 , 2 0 1 8 B a ll ro o m 1 B a ll ro o m 2 B a ll ro m m 3 Ju n io r B a ll ro o m 2 M e e ti n g R o o m 1 M e e ti n g R o o m 2 07 :0 0 - 08 :0 0 R eg is tr at io n D is ea se O ra l Pr es en ta ti o n 3 O ra l Pr es en ta ti o n 4 M o d er at ed Po st er Pr es en ta ti o n 2 15 :1 0 - 1 6: 20 Sy m p o si u m 1 0 Pe di at ri c Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Here's a link to the regex above applied to the example text:
https://regex101.com/r/utVcRy/1

An acceptable answer when applied to the example block of text might look similar to this (the digits and punctuation may be ignored - the regex I've written so far doesn't select them, which is fine):

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Registration Counter - Prefunction Area Level 1 09:00 - 12:00 Registration 12:00 - 13:00 Lunch 13:00 - 19:00 Registration PROGRAM AT GLANCE Saturday,September1,2018Ballroom1Ballroom2Ballromm3JuniorBallroom2MeetingRoom1MeetingRoom207:00-08:00RegistrationDiseaseOralPresentation3OralPresentation4ModeratedPosterPresentation215:10-16:20Symposium10Pediatric Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: Do you need help with this?

Comment: Not any more, but thanks. I solved it using a combination of regex and string handling within Python.

Comment: Then please post your solution as an answer and accept it to finalize this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the regex from the question to extract the problem blocks, then used Python to remove the whitespace:

```py
spaceless_blocks = set(re.findall(r"((?:\s\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\b){3,})", content))

# Need to sort by descending length so that shorter subsets don't prevent replace finding the longer blocks
spaceless_blocks = sorted(spaceless_blocks, key=len, reverse=True)

for block in spaceless_blocks:
    # Only attempt a fix if the block is large enough to be worth it
    if len(block) > 10:
        compressed = block.replace(' ', '')
        # then do stuff with the compressed block...
```